# AWS IoT - Two devices using the same clientId and certs cause re-connections error

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-iot

I have a simple nodejs AWS Iot device implementation.

```
var awsIot = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');

const device = awsIot.device({
    keyPath: 'private.pem.key',
    certPath: 'certificate.pem.crt',
    caPath: 'CA.pem',
    clientId: 'device1',
    host: 'xxxxyyyyy1.iot.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com'
});

device.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('DEVICE connect!');
});
device.on('message', (topic, payload) => {
    console.log('DEVICE message!');
});
device.on('close', () => {
    console.log('DEVICE closed!');
});
device.on('error', error => {
    console.log('DEVICE error!');
    console.log(error);
});
device.on('offline', () => {
    console.log('DEVICE offline!');
});
```

The script runs fine if I execute a single instance of it.
Output:

```
dev@dev1:~/dev$ node test1.js
DEVICE connect!
```

However, if I run the same script on two different machines simultaneously, both devices repeatedly disconnects and reconnects.

```
dev@dev1:~/dev$ node test1.js
DEVICE connect!
DEVICE offline!
DEVICE closed!
DEVICE connect!
DEVICE offline!
DEVICE closed!
DEVICE connect!
DEVICE offline!
DEVICE closed!
DEVICE connect!
^C
dev@dev1:~/dev$


dev@dev2:~/dev$ node test1.js
DEVICE connect!
DEVICE offline!
DEVICE closed!
DEVICE connect!
DEVICE offline!
DEVICE closed!
DEVICE connect!
DEVICE offline!
DEVICE closed!
DEVICE connect!
^C
dev@dev2:~/dev2$
```

AWS Security Policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From AWS-IoT docs

> The message broker uses the client ID to identify each client. The client ID is passed in from the client to the message broker as part of the MQTT payload. Two clients with the same client ID are not allowed to be connected concurrently to the message broker. When a client connects to the message broker using a client ID that another client is using, a CONNACK message will be sent to both clients and the currently connected client will be disconnected.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/protocols.html

Answer (score 1):

Well in MQTT, the protocol AWS IoT is using, the Clientid should be unique per Device

> The client identifier (ClientId) identifies each MQTT client that
>   connects to an MQTT broker. The broker uses the ClientID to identify
>   the client and the current state of the client.Therefore, this ID
>   should be unique per client and broker. In MQTT 3.1.1 (the current
>   standard), you can send an empty ClientId, if you don’t need a state
>   to be held by the broker. The empty ClientID results in a connection
>   without any state. In this case, the clean session flag must be set to
>   true or the broker will reject the connection.

The Client ID is also used for Client Takeover which causes your problem

> Usually, a disconnected client tries to reconnect. Sometimes, the
>   broker still has an half-open connection for the client. In MQTT, if
>   the broker detects a half-open connection, it performs a ‘client
>   take-over’. The broker closes the previous connection to the same
>   client (determined by the client identifier), and establishes a new
>   connection with the client. This behavior ensures that the half-open
>   connection does not stop the disconnected client from re-establishing
>   a connection.

https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials/